# how can I utilized table widgets in another class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have an UI designed in QT Designer. It is formed from 2 tabs

1 - choosefile.ui; 2 - showTable.ui;

I have two classes for each tab in First class i have one  button(to choose file) and a label(which shows the count of files) and another button(get files) in a 2nd class i have only table and a back button.

by clicking on get files button I want to show  **all files that I selected(with QFileDialog) with random numbers.**

This is my current code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton,
                              QLabel, QLineEdit,
                              QMessageBox,QCheckBox,QFrame,
                              QStackedWidget,QFileDialog)
from PyQt5 import uic
class ChooseFile(QWidget):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         uic.loadUi("choosefile.ui", self)
         self.setWindowTitle("choose file")
         

         # button_submitt 
         btn = self.findChild(QPushButton,"btn_choose_file")
         btn.clicked.connect(self.upload_file)
         # label shows count of files
         label = self.findChild(QLabel,"label")
         btn2 = self.findChild(QPushButton,"btn_get_files")
         btn2.clicked.connect(self.get_file)
         
     def upload_file(self):
         
         filter = "TXT (*.txt);;PDF (*.pdf)"
         file_name = QFileDialog()
         file_name.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
         filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Upload File","",
                                                    filter)
         file_count = len(filename[0])
         if filename:
             if (file_count>1):
                    self.label.setText(str(file_count)+" files selected")
             else:
                 self.label.setText(str(filename[0]))
     def get_file(self):
         next_page = TableFile()
         widget.addWidget(next_page)
         widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
         
class TableFile(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("showTable.ui", self)
        
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0,100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1,100)
        btn_back = self.findChild(QPushButton,"btn_back")
        btn_back.clicked.connect(self.back)
        
    def back(self):
       back_page = ChooseFile()
       widget.addWidget(back_page)
       widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() - 1)
    

        
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

ch = ChooseFile()
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(ch)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. Add an argument to the `__init__` and provide the list of files; 2. Don't use `findChild` as it's pointless, all widgets created by uic are already instance attributes based on their object name (`self.btn_choose_file`, etc.) 3. I strongly suggest to *completely* ignore the YouTube tutorial you're probably following, as it's known to provide a lot of terrible suggestions and bad practices, and we get statistically a post a day with people having issues caused by that. Seriously, it's just that bad.

Comment: how i provide the list of files ?

Comment: Add it as an argument to the constructor: `ChooseFile(someList)` and then add an argument to the `__init__` so that you can process it. If you don't understand that, I strongly suggest you to do some research on using classes and arguments in their constructors (which work just like functions, by the way), as this is a very basic knowledge for python.

Comment: @musicamante i am stuck, got a lot of silly errors

Comment: Sorry, but, as said, these are very basic concepts of Python. I'd suggest to start with the tutorials provided on wiki.python.org and expand your knowledge on the above subjects.